# Using reflection to create an instance

Tags: c#, .net

To create an instance of a class we can do that :

```
Person p = new Person();
```

But, I want to pass the name of class dynamicaly with a string like that :

```
String name = "Human.Person"
name n = new name();
```

I know this is wrong but I saw that I can use reflection but I didn't understand how can I use it for my case.

Comment: Also I've removed the visual studio tag.  Please only include relevant tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Activator.CreateInstance for this scenario.

```
object person = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Human.Person"));
```

or most commonly using a base class or interface:

```
IPerson person = (IPerson)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Human.Person"));
```

Comment: And if I want to open a form like : `Class c = new Class(); c.Show();` ?

Comment: Your class will inherit from Form, so you can use Form c = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance( ... )

Comment: Like that : `Form c = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Human.Person");` ? I have a ArgumentNullException

Comment: My Bad, an error in my class name. Now it works thx

Answer (score 1):

```
  Type t = Type.GetType(name); 
  Human.Person p = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Human.Person;
```

Updated: 
Thanks @Dag
If Human.person is in another assembly

```
Type t = a.GetType(name, "assemblyName"); 
Human.Person p = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as Human.Person;
```

Comment: You don't need to load it, just add the assembly name to the type name like this "Human.Person,something"

Comment: You are right. Thanks